# Kobayashi hyperbolic complex Lie groups

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

In "HOLOMORPHIC FIBER BUNDLES WITH HYPERBOLIC FIBER 1" by H. L. ROYDEN, it was proved that a holomorphic fiber bundle with simply connected base
and Kobayashi hyperbolic fiber is trivial. Now given a complex Lie group $G$ and a holomorphic $G$-principle fiber bundle $E$ over a simply connected complex manifold, may one applies the above theorem in this case? Namely, whether  a complex Lie group $G$ is Kobayashi hyperbolic. If not in general, is it Kobayashi hyperbolic for $G=GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ or $G=PGL_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Every "root" of a semisimple complex Lie group $G$ gives a homomorphism of complex Lie groups $\mathbb{C} \to G$ that is injective.  Since $G$ contains entire holomorphic curves, it is not Kobayashi hyperbolic.  Maybe the Kobayashi pseudometric is identically zero (I could ask one expert that I know, but you might be able to find this for yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A complex Lie group is never Kobayashi hyperbolic, as the exponential map applied to any complex line in the Lie algebra gives a complex line in the group.

Comment: In fact, since it is connected by such complex lines and their translates, its Kobayashi pseudometric is zero.

Comment: The hyperbolic plane has a real Lie group structure with a left invariant complex structure (isomorphic to the disk in the complex plane) in which it is Kobayashi hyperbolic.

Comment: More generally, if a complex manifold has a holomorphic vector field $X$ so that $X$ and $iX$ are complete, then the complex manifold contains a complex line through every point, so the Kobayashi pseudometric is degenerate everywhere.